# I need to extract a data validated cell content and use it as a part of a new formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to give the user the option to choose between `DAYS360()` and `NETWORKDAYS()`.
For that, I thought about adding these 2 to a data validation cell.

Afterwards, I would like to be able to add that choice as part of a new formula that calculates the worked days as such:

```
=DAYS360(D12,E12)
```

Can that be accomplished within Google Sheets without scripts?
I've tried myself some formulas, but couldn't get to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [drop-down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103) with the values `elapsed calendar days` and `working days` in cell A12. Then use this formula:

```
=ifs(
  A12 = "elapsed calendar days", days360(D12, E12), 
  A12 = "working days", networkdays(D12, E12), 
  true, iferror(1/0) 
)
```